# Deal with toxic manager when you can't quit

Tags: manager, stress, france

At my first job, I had the bad luck to get a manager that was very toxic.

This reached the point of him driving most of the team to quit. 
In the three months I was there, he drove 5 people to quit (in a team composed of 12 people), and was getting close to drive the rest of the team to quit.

To give a perspective of why he was toxic:

- Constantly undermining every one's work by saying thing like "I could have done it in one hour" or "That was really easy, don't be too proud of yourself"
- Constantly failing to meet deadlines, which resulted in everyone else (not him) staying overtime trying to make things right (We once had to wait for 3 weeks, for a vital piece of information, and when he delivered it to us, we were one week behind the deadline).
- Berating the team for using their rights, such as overtime pay.

At the time, I was lucky enough to have the opportunity to leave without too many consequences. But a colleague there was not so lucky, as he needed this job to sustain his family.

This made me wonder, if there exists any method to, at the very least, mitigate the stress induced by this kind of manager? When quitting is not an option, and you have to stick with the job?

As suggested a little more precision on the situation:

This happened in France, in a region where the supply of software developers is far higher than the demand, and leaving your job can lead to several months of job hunting.

In France, when you quit, it is harder to get monetary compensation than if you are let go.

Also, there were only two people above this manager, there had already been complaints made, but they did not do anything, because he had way too many responsibilities, and the company was basically tied to him, for better or for worse.

From the answers and comment, it seems most people agree on the fact that quitting is always an option. I do not think this is true, it might be true in some areas of the world, but in many other, it's not.

While France is not the worst country in the world when it comes to employment, there is a lot of things that makes it quite hard to find a job, especially in areas such as Software Development. Most companies asks for diplomas, not experiences.

I did not think that getting in the specific of this colleague's situation was necessary, but I think I was wrong, the reason he was not able to quit :

- His wife was pregnant, and was due in less than a month (at the time I left) with their 2nd child.
- They had a mortgage on their house, so moving was not an option.
- He had already works in other industries, but due to health conditions he could not keep working physical jobs, he was not disabled, but was advised to stop those job to avoid becoming disabled.

Comment: @Whysmerhill as stated before the comments were deleted, the region we were in was filled with students and graduate, so 99% of IT jobs required yout to have a BAC+5 at the least if you wanted a chance. He was actively looking, had been for several month, but nothing came of it.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

First of all, **quitting is always an option**.  What would your colleague do if the company suddenly closed its doors?  (This happens, and the employees are usually the last to see it coming).

Your colleague needs to **stop making excuses and start job hunting for real.**  It may take a long time, but there are better jobs and non-toxic managers out there.

In the meantime, there are a couple of things your colleague  can do:

> Constantly undermining every one's work by saying thing like "I could have done it in one hour"

- Remember that this person is toxic and whatever comes out of their mouth is not relevant or meaningful.  Stop caring about this manager's opinion.

> Constantly failing to meet deadlines

- Keep a written log of what was promised, when, and by whom.  When anything happens, log that as well (what, when, by whom).  It's a major pain in the rear to do, but when the grand boss comes around looking for necks to choke it will not only protect you, it may shine some unwanted light on the toxic manager.

> Berating the team for using their rights, such as overtime pay

- Same as above - keep a log about what was earned, paid, etc. and remember that the babbling of fools is best ignored as much as possible.
- If the colleague is paid hourly, then not receiving overtime pay is something to take up with HR or the union, if there is one.  If the colleague is salaried and this is "comp time", then the right answer might be to stop working the overtime to begin with (so there's nothing to comp)

Comment: If the company closed its door, this employee would receive monetary compensation (this happens in france) it would not be a lot, but enough to sustain his family. If he had quit, he would not have received any kind of money before a minimum of 3 month. He was actively looking, but it was in a region where the software development supply was far, far higher than the demand. Moving was not an option for them.

Comment: That's good to know.  In the US, it's possible for the company to close and the employees are suddenly out of work with no warning and no compensation.

Comment: Perhaps the colleague can find remote work?  In software development it's not always necessary to be in the same room to produce code.

Comment: Also all details and proofs of the overtime work can later be used to eventually receive compensation once your colleague has found a new job and left the old one. Just consult your local authority regarding labour.

Comment: @DanPichelman That's not true in the US. We get benefits via unemployment insurance, funded by specific state and federal taxes on employers. Same situation: quitting voluntarily disqualifies you for unemployment.

Comment: @user71659 - You're right of course.  I tend to forget that unemployment insurance exists... not sure why.

Comment: Good advice, I'd add one bit: Whenever it becomes obvious that some required information/component isn't delivered in time and this has a likely effect on meeting a promised deadline, make that clear. Regularly, if necessary every day in the standup, mention that this piece of information is missing and that every day it keeps being missing will likely move the deadline one day into the future. If possible, put the adjusted deadline somewhere for the whole team do see. Communicate loudly, this way it's clear to everyone why eventually things will be past the original deadline.

Comment: Loudly, but not accusatory, it's not you who are toxic, after all. Feel free to incorporate that advice if you want into your answer.

Comment: +1 for "quitting is always an option".  Sometimes for mental or physical or relationship health reasons you *have* to quit.

Comment: French labor regulations have badly distorted the labor market there.  Yes, you *can* quit in the sense that nobody will put you in jail if you do, but it's frequently a very bad idea.

Comment: @bob I have to disagree with "quitting is always an option", in many areas in the world, having a job is not a right, it's not a given, it's a luxury, and quitting said job can be very, very dangerous. Actually there is countries where quitting is the same as giving up your career.

Comment: I have quite a few colleagues who have moved job but not house. They work here Monday to Friday and go home at the weekend, until they get things sorted. This sounds hard, but they say that because of long working hours they only saw their children at the weekend anyway.

Comment: While this is a good answer, you should re-work the start. France has social security systems, and if you lose your job you get compensation (assurance chômage). If you quit on your own you do not get compensation for at least three months (IIRC, I am not French). So yes, there is a significant financial difference between quitting and being let go. So yes, quitting is always an option, but *it is not the same* as the company closing down.

Comment: I'm accepting this anwser, as I believe it's the one with the most useful advices to deal with such situations

Comment: @user3399 "but enough to sustain his family" - but for how long?  Getting a new job is ALWAYS harder when you don't have one than when you do.  That said - I think this answer is missing a very important part - collect the colleagues contact details for references and referrals.  You can expect this manager to be a poor reference giver, so it's time to start making sure you can get a good one.

Comment: +1 "quitting is always an option" - I disagree. (Technically, yes you can quit. In reality, Nope. you can't) However, this might be true in some countries (like the US, Canada, etc).

Comment: Quitting **is** always an option. It might be an option that has enormous downsides, it might be an option you decide not to take very early in your decision making process, but you are **never** obliged to remain in a job - unless you are literally enslaved (in which case you probably won't have the freedom to ask questions on Stack Exchange). "I choose not to quit this job because of X, Y and Z" is a valid statement (and X, Y, and Z may be very good reasons). "I cannot quit this job" is not a valid statement.

Comment: Suggesting to quit is terrible advice. I literary got into a severe depression for which ended when I attempted suicided (which put me in a trajectory where I have less stress) during my "job hunt" due to the stress from constant rejection upon rejection upon rejection. - It's not healthy to hunt for jobs.

Comment: Quitting is always an option, therefore can we please stop mentioning that in almost every answer? OP even said that he wants different advice and had to add irrelevant text to respond to all the quitting answers.

Comment: Similar to the argument in the comments on the question over the use of the word 'literally', context is important.  It's unhelpful to hard on about quitting always being an option.  It might be technically true, but it's safe to say that in this context, 'not an option' is shorthand for 'not an acceptable option'.

Comment: "Quitting is always an option" can be rephrased as "X is always an option", where X represents anything from committing suicide to robbing a bank to stowing away on a freighter headed for another country. The fact that ridiculous options exist is not useful information to anyone dealing with such a situation.

Comment: @paul23 And you think the manager OP is describing would have been better for your mental health?

Comment: Well, if the guy has a mortgage in Lozère or other jobless areas of France, nope, quitting is NOT an option.

Comment: Am I the only person who interprets "you should quit" as meaning "go find another job but still keep the current one while you look"? At least for most situations. Everybody knows it is far easier to find a new job while you actually have a job. It only makes sense to keep the current job while looking for a new one, no point in quitting immediately and giving yourself a double-whammy of no income and more difficult to find next job because you are unemployed.

Comment: @Dunk - Thanks for your comment - that was the primary point of my answer, but it seems many people stop reading after the first paragraph.

Comment: @DanPichelman No, I didn't stop reading. It's just annoying that even when the OP explicitly asks for other options, people start their answers with "you should quit" responses. OP felt forced to add 7 paragraphs to explain the situation, your answer starts with 2 paragraphs to explain the obvious "quitting is always an option". In my opinion that's useless fluff.

Answer (score 95):

To reduce the stress: Stop caring. After 8 hours work a day, stop working. If the manager makes it hard to leave, stop working and get overtime pay without working. If he says “I could have done that in an hour” you say “of course you could” so he doesn’t see you getting upset (because that’s what he wants) while thinking to yourself what you actually think of him. Same if he says “that was really easy”, you say “absolutely, that was really easy, you could have done that in an hour”.

He knows what he is, and you know what he is, so make it clear without saying anything bad that you know and you don’t care. It’s only stress if you care.

@strader: You wouldn't feel belittled if your five year old son said "I could have done that in an hour". Once you change your mental attitude, that boss isn't any more clever than your five year old son, so you don't feel belittled. You know which one is the child and which one the adult.

Comment: I disagree, being belittled on regular basis is stressful for any person.

Comment: The best answer to "I could have done that in an hour" is "then you don't need me to do it". If he follows that by suggesting that you should quit if you think so then the answer should be "I don't think so, but if you do, you know what to do". This, of course, does not help in the stress mitigation issue, but at least puts limits into his insolence and allows to move forward onto the inevitable outcome.

Comment: +1 from me. Just remember nothing is forever and this too shall pass. Instead of thinking "How am I going to live like this?" change your mindset and remember it is only a period of time (just like any other period of time of your life!). Just do your work, start looking for something else, and try not to think about it much. It is not your life after all, it is just a job and there are millions of them out there. It is not the only job in the world and they are not all like this!

Comment: +1, lol, if the job is terrible what do they expect.  I think as a manager, you have to lower your expectations on employees when the job is miserable.

Comment: @Strader I'm pretty sure that is *not* true. Further, it is not true most commonly when people don't care what the belittling person is saying. The tricky part for many (but not everyone) is the "stop caring" part.

Comment: I have worked for a guy like that, and it does grind you down. Especially as he belittled us to other people too.

Comment: I like the advice, but "stop caring" is hardly something one can decide just like this... The level of "caring" about such things is I think part of everyone's personality, and changing a trait of your personality requires quite some work and effort, even if eventually there are huge benefits

Comment: Especially in France : if you stop caring and the manager decides to let you go, the severance package is usually very good + you get unemployment (which you don't if you quit by yourself)

Comment: I both agree and disagree with this answer.  To clarify: Some people are unusually sensitive to words and demeanor.  My partner is acutely capable of brushing things off and not allowing anyone to get under their skin. I, on the other hand, could be fully aware that someone is nothing more than a boaster... but still take negative comments and berating to heart anyway and feel emotionally distressed.  This answer is great for some, but I wouldn't say everyone.

Comment: If I hadn't already added this stack to my profile, I would have done so just to upvote this answer. "It’s only stress if you care." Brilliant.

Comment: @DerekElkins Not caring AT ALL for anything that is said to you by others is a definition of sociopath. i am not a 100% certain, but OP is not one

Comment: @Strader I don't know why you feel the need to stretch things. No one said anything about not caring about anything that anyone says to you. The (stereotypical) sociopath *can't* care about anyone else. What "stop caring" really means in this context is that you don't need to give *everyone you interact with* leverage over your emotional state and self-worth. For example, say you are front-line tech support for a company, you don't need to be a sociopath to understand that most of the abuse you may receive is not informed by your behavior and therefore shouldn't be taken personally.

Comment: @DerekElkins sure, but if they leave a review that shits on you it may still impact your work and pay. You can control your emotional reaction all you want, but you cannot control the reaction of your co-workers, if your boss is undermining you to your peers and their bosses this can be stressful and cause problems even if you can play off being a hindu cow to their faces and ignore the direct attacks.

Comment: @crasic I more or less agree with all of that. I'm not suggesting that you behave completely passively or that there aren't *other* issues related to this that you need to deal with. I'm also not saying this isn't a toxic situation even if you do "stop caring". However, the issues you mention can come up even if the manager is completely charming to you. (They might even be worse in that case.)

Comment: i get these comments.  I respond in slack.... "ok thanks" . he types 4 more sentences and a say.... "ok thanks"    no stress

Answer (score 22):

> Constantly failing to meet deadlines, which resulted in everyone else (not him) to stay overtime to try and makes things right (We once had to wait 3 week, for a vital piece of information, and when he delivered it to us, we were one week behind the deadline).

There's a very simple answer to this. The deadline slips. And as much as managers love to say "but that's not acceptable", the answer is simply "but it's going to happen".

And you don't just tell him this. You copy his manager, and his manager's manager. You say what the original plans were, and that because your manager started you all on this late, it'll take that long. And you make sure it takes that long!

For bonus points, you can say "we're all prepared to do overtime to help out the company so it'll only slip by two weeks". Then you look proactive and helpful - but the deadline slip still happens, and management know it's down to your boss.

> Berating the team for using their rights, such as overtime pay.

Now this is crazy stuff. If your contract says you get this, then you get it. If he pushes it, the next step is to call HR and say "John thinks we shouldn't be claiming overtime pay. Please can you tell me what our contract says? And please can you email that section of the contract to me and John, so we know for the future?" Especially getting email evidence.

Comment: And if they're in France, there's always an HT to appeal to, and bad legal consequences for not following the labor laws.  At least if you lose your job because of insisting on your rights you can go to the prudhommes (labor tribunal) and get compensation.  As long as you're careful to document everything

Answer (score 12):

1) As has been said elsewhere, quitting is always an option.  It depends on what you are willing to sacrifice, but quitting is never "not an option".

2) I don't know anything about French work culture, but in North America where I am also a software developer like your colleague, it is perfectly reasonable for an employee to job hunt *while working*.  You don't have to quit and be out of a job before you start job hunting; when you know that you want to leave, start looking for another job, and then you can seamlessly move from one job to the next easily.

My advice to your coworker (former co-worker?) would be to start job hunting ASAP, while continuing to work.  He should continue to do his job to the best of his ability, and try to ignore the stupid stuff from his manager as best he can in the meantime, and then as soon as he finds something else, he should jump ship.

Answer (score 10):

Just have a very short 1:1; **tell your manager that you fell in love with him**, that you have finally given up on having a relationship and just wanted to take this off your chest. Practice a lot so that you can say this with a straight face.

Once you have declared your love, he will no longer be able to avoid feeling weird and uncomfortable every time he looks at you, forever. With some luck, communication will be cut to a minimum and you will never be asked again to stay in the office a minute longer than necessary. It's not against the law, and if he tries to fire you to spare himself the embarrassment you will get compensated more than adequately.
It's a WIN-WIN, but both wins are for you.

Comment: This can go wrong in so many ways.

Comment: That requires a lot of courage and good acting to go well. And even if it does, the boss is likely to force incidents that would allow him to fire the employee under whatever is the french equivalent of fair cause, even if he actually fires the person without fair cause claim. I would say this is reasonable advice if the person wants to be fired or is willing to risk it, not if he needs to stay.

Comment: upvote for the lolz, though.

Comment: In the US this would probably constitute sexual harassment.

Comment: Bahaha I love this answer

Comment: surprisingly good answer. Think out of the box. 
As long as he's not in love himself.

Comment: And that's when you realize your boss is gay, and was also secretely in love with you...

Comment: This is terrible advice.

Comment: Why does this have a score of 5? This will likely backfire and it could also be morally wrong for some people to confess their love for people they don't actually love.

Comment: You sir just won the internet.

Comment: I like the idea, but it could backfire so badly ... what if he then decides to "act on this love", or what if he calls out "sexual harassment" ?
Had this been a comment I'd have given it seven upvotes for the lolz, but I don't think this is an appropriate answer to deal with the situation.

Answer (score 7):

I have unfortunately been in this situation. I had been with the company for 2 years longer than my supervisor and she was totally clueless and attempting to fire all of her own employees to the point that I was the last developer standing (sounds kind of crazy when your job is to supervise those employees). She had actually written me up twice for things that were to basically cover her own issues. While this was going on I basically quit talking to her any more than I had to and had my headphone on at all times and sent an email to the HR department and the president of the company informing them of everything she had been doing. Luckily they finally saw her for what she was and she was the one fired in the end and I stayed on at that company for a few more years.

The basics being, do your job, document everything, and sooner or later those at the top will see what is happening and justice will be served, and if not hopefully a new position can be found soon.

Comment: Upvoted until I reached 'sent an email to the HR department and the president of the company informing them of everything she had been doing. Luckily they finally saw her for what she was and she was the one fired in the end'... and then everyone on the bus stood up and clapped.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with most of the answers here. In particular, quitting is always an option, be job hunting already, and stop caring about what the manager is saying (except, obviously, that which is necessary to do your job).

The only addition here is to operationalize the "stop caring" part a bit. The people for whom simply telling them to stop caring is enough to accomplish that are not the people who need to be told it as they will have already stopped caring.

My suggestion is to reframe the situation in your head. Specifically, reframe the manager as just an obstactle. Dealing with the manager's crap is just an (unpleasant) part of the job, no different from dealing with a broken printer, say. Sure it's annoying, but it isn't personal and your mind goes to questions like "Can I fix the printer? Can I get the printer to do what I want despite being broken? Can I work around the printer? Can I accomplish what I need without the printer?" You don't wonder why the printer is so unfair to you.

Here's a more or less equivalent alternative reframing. View your job like a video game. You're trying to do the best job you can. Your manager is like a bad guy trying to thwart you. Not a boss, mind you, just one of the regularly occurring goombas. You're not personally aggrieved by the fact that the goombas in Mario are trying to impede you. You just think about the best strategy to get past them. Again, your mindset when playing a video game is that given this is the way the world is set up, what is the best strategy to navigate through it?

A third that's slightly different but mostly the same is to imagine your manager as a big parrot. If a parrot said belittling things to you, you wouldn't take it personally. The parrot is just making noise, and what it says has much more to do with it than you. This is likely true for your manager too.

The common thread through all of these, just to lay it out, is that you are intentionally dehumanizing your manager. Doing this removes most of the weight from what they say.

Clearly, this is not an ideal situation, and I'm not suggesting the above *in lieu of* finding a better job.

Answer (score 2):

The immature way to deal with toxic people who you can't remove from your life, assuming you've already had a sit down with them and explained why their behavior is unacceptable, is to cut them down back.

For example, "I could have done that in an hour" should be answered with something like "You sure you're sober?" or "I'd like to see you try".

Refusing to pay for work should be met with "No money, no honey" and followed up by you not showing up to work the next day for whatever reason - probably sick time, it honestly doesn't matter if it gets approved or not because you're sending a message.

That piece of information you didn't get that put the entire team behind schedule should be something that the manager is never allowed to forget. Bring it up every time it might be relevant.

This is the wrong thing to do, but if you can't quit and really want things to work out, you're going to have to discipline your manager.

The professional thing to do is to document this behavior, send it to your managers superiors even though you know they won't do anything, and find another job. Look for a job while you still have one and then stop working with the toxic manager as soon as you get a new job. People like this are going to have a much bigger impact on your career than they have any right to if you keep working for them.

Comment: Unfortunately this (especially not showing up) might lead to negative consequences up to firing the employee on their fault (which would probably also leave them with no compensation).

Comment: @Ister it should, but it won't. If there's an exit interview at your company this manager will get fired over not paying you over time and the like. Managers generally have more to lose too. Given the rest of this toxic manager's stats, 50% of a team you count yourself, the manager won't do anything. The toxic manager really can't do anything without hurting themselves.

Comment: @Ister  "Unfortunately this (especially not showing up) might lead to negative consequences up to firing the employee on their fault " Employment is when an employee does work, and their employer gives them money. So if the employer isn't giving them money, the employment has already been terminated. You can't not pay someone, and then claim that the termination was for cause because they stopped working for free.

Comment: Let me phrase it like this: I've been in a situation worse that described here. I wasn't given even my regular salary for some period. It does not automatically void your contract (at least in Europe). You have to cancel it (of course you can do so without a notice period). It means for instance that the employer owes you money for your work, whether they like or not. And there are ways to enforce that (I received mine, after my contract was terminated). Apparently OP's colleague cannot afford to loose job right now so they should collect all evidence to be able to reclaim their money later.

Comment: @Ister sounds like you should post your own answer

Comment: @Steve it would be mostly copy of the accepted answer. I might add few cents that he might consider introducing into his answer though.

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: IMHO this is only my 2 cents on the situation, read from few lines of description, be aware of this.

People under a toxic manager should put **first** their health (mental and physical). If you (or your colleagues) are not able to understand this, you are hurting yourself. 
So put first point of the list, in this environment, your side.

This require a lot of internal work and of course you can ask for help from family, friends and even meet with colleagues under this toxic manager could help. *You must solve first how to not explode*, in any way under a toxic manager. I'm thinking about NOT, NEVER, EVER:

- yell out
- physical attacks

If you are able to control your reactions "outside" of your body, you are on the right path on my side.

After this is important to take your time, at least one hour per day, to analyze your work routine, where you can improve. An example is: "how can I interact less with this manager?" or "I should have said something when.." etc..
This exercise will not help immediately, but will help after some weeks. You will be aware of the situation, in control of your reactions and more importantly (like other said) be able to react better and more professionaly, when this toxic manager enter in the room.

After this, remember one golden rule: toxic manager need employees to be bully with. Without them, manager is nothing, only an empty shell. If you can on this realization (and takes times) you will put all the situation on the right perspective.

It's only a job! **Job is important, yes, but is not all your life**. You can search and change the job. But scars of this situation will be with you even after some years. You have to come out with some insight about yourself, how to handle this kind of situation, control your reaction in public and handle toxic manager.

One example:

> We once had to  wait for 3 weeks, for a vital piece of information, and when he
>   delivered it to us, we were one week behind the deadline).

If this happened to me, after two/three days of waiting (maybe less, dpends on the exact situation). I started with:

- email every day to remember that you are waiting for this crucial information
- phone manager at least one/two times per day and report this in emails
- bring manager on details

Last point is most important, because you mention this manager said:

> Constantly undermining every one's work by saying thing like "I could
>   have done it in one hour" or "That was really easy, don't be too proud
>   of yourself"

This is good! You can use this to prove the exact opposite.

**Software development is all about small details** in chain, to make things work. Bring manager on details, smaller is better. One hour will fly, you know it.
Do it again, again and again. Do this not only by yourself, but with other three/four people. Toxic manager will explode for sure.
Like other said, log by email everything, include manager on emails and if he/she does not responde, log to upper management.

BUT a crucial point. **Be professional**. Jokes, sarcasm.. put aside all of this. Main point here is to do the job during normal hours. Your focus should be commited to complete the job and prove that you are doing this, without any doubt.

This is an example, but I think you understand what I'm saying.

In conclusion:

- put the situation on right perspective,
- be aware you your reactions and control them,
- log everything,
- don't do overtime,
- bring manager to smaller details,
- report to upper management,
- be professional,
- search for a new job

**Plus note**: there are a lot of remote jobs opportunities, a lot of ads even here on stackoverflow/stackexcange, take a look on them.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you were in a position where you depend on the income and thus cannot just walk away from your current job, that does not prevent you from looking for another job and staying with your current employer until you have signed a contract elsewhere.

Depending on your company, changing teams may also be an option. You might be able to bring this up with your boss’s boss, but only after considering the circumstances of your case: If the boss and his boss are best buddies, you are unlikely to get any support from there. Otherwise, it is ultimately not in the interest of the company to have a manager that burns through employees at a high rate—unless your company has a culture of turning a blind eye to such behavior. If you find that is the case, you should definitely find a job elsewhere.

Until then, reduce your involvement in your job. Do just enough to not get fired. French employment law, to my knowledge, is very much in favor of employees, and your employer cannot simply let you go without there being a serious reason for it. What I would suggest:

- If you need input from your boss or anyone else to do your work, request it in writing, and follow up on it in writing if still nothing happens.
- Keep a paper trail of everything that happened, especially others failing to meet a deadline, so you have proof should anyone try to blame you.
- Do not go out of your way to cover up for your manager’s failure to do his job. As the saying goes: **Lack of planning on your part does not constitute an emergency on my part.**
- Remember that, as long as you deliver average performance, you have fulfilled your side of the deal. You are not required to excel.
- Do not provide your company any reasons to fire you. Make sure you fulfill your contractual obligations. Be present during core working hours (if defined by your contract), do not use your computer for non-work-related purposes unless explicitly allowed by your company, and the like.
- Do not work more than the hours you are contractually obliged to work. (Remember that looking for a new job is a task in itself which requires energy.)
- Take your contractual days off. You do not have to earn your vacation, it is part of your contract.
- When you are sick, take the sick leave to which you are entitled by law.
- When your manager makes personal comments, do your best to ignore them. If you have a different source of appreciation, that is even better and helps you put your manager’s comments into perspective. (Quite likely, he is belittling others in order to divert attention from his own flaws.)
- If your manager berates you for claiming your contractual or legal rights, at the most state that you are entitled to them by law/that they are part of your contract, and that you hereby consider the issue settled. Or do not comment at all.

It may still be a tough time, but you can make sure it is going to be temporary.

Answer (score 1):

This is not unique to France in any way.

- Pretty much everywhere in the world, quitting voluntarily disqualifies you from unemployment benefits. (otherwise, why not just quit once a year to have a 3-months paid holiday, then get hired again?)
- When you have a mortgage and you need to move, you either sell your house or you rent it out (and put the rent towards monthly loan payments). If you can't do those things, you're essentially worth zero financially and you don't earn enough money to own a house.
- Someone who became a software developer because they had to quit doing physical labor will always be at disadvantage vs. someone with a degree in programming.

In the short term, your friend should try to cope with their boss, complain to HR about blatant cases, and perhaps get the worker's union involved. In the long term however, they should honestly answer two questions:

- Are they any good at their job?
- Can they afford the lifestyle they currently have?

If they aren't good at their job, they will never get a decent one which they will be able to hold onto. There are good companies with nice bosses out there, but these have the luxury of hiring people with impressive CVs, and firing someone who doesn't perform well.

If they live beyond their means, they will eventually get bankrupt. They will have to let the house go, better sooner than later. Waiting for things to improve is not going to work, because kids only become more expensive as they grow, and your friend won't get younger either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this question from a different perspective.  Instead of telling you what you should do (quit, look for another job, etc) - ***I'm going to give you some things that helped me get through when this sort of thing happened to me.  Because, well, I had a very similar boss for about 18 months.***

---

**First up: Forget about Validation.**  Ordinarily, your boss saying "Good job!" or "I'm disappointed in you" should have an effect on you, because you have respect for your boss and their opinion matters to you.  But in a situation like this, you need to let it go.  Your mantra should be: "Why does this guy get to determine whether I'm happy?"  I'm not saying to disrespect him, to be sarcastic to him, to backtalk, or anything like that (that's not generally going to go well) - just to put a mental buffer whenever he says something stupid/demeaning.  'He said that would only take him 1 hour?  Eh, whatever.  I'm happy that I did a good job because of X, Y, and Z.'

**Second: Be professional and it's tough to be fired.**  The funny thing about places with incredibly high turnover is that's harder for the manager to pull the trigger to fire someone for silly reasons.  Why?  Because the in-house knowledge is spread far too thinly.  Most of the people are new, after all!  When I was at the end of my 18 month stint with the toxic boss, and I gave my 2 weeks notice?  My boss noticed that I was *only* putting in 40 hours a week the last few months (he'd been trying to force 45-50 hour weeks as the baseline).  But his reaction *wasn't* "Good riddance, you lazy bum!" but was "And I can't convince you to stay?  Listen, if you ever need a job, please let me know."  I was professional, diligent, did a good job, and knew my way around the SQL databases.  Not only was he not going to fire me, but was trying to convince me to stay at only 40 hours/week.

**Third: Mentally project yourself in his shoes.**  Do *NOT* get me wrong - I'm not saying that your boss is right/smart/good/decent/whatever.  I'm saying that he's a terrible communicator with anger issues.  A regular boss can simply tell you their priorities; a regular boss can understand if something unexpected comes up.  A terrible boss doesn't do either... so it's really important to try to figure out the boss' priorities.  For instance, the toxic boss of mine would scream at us when he felt we weren't being productive... and he would scream at us when we missed deadlines.  But the reason he screamed at 'not productive' was because he was worried about 'missing deadlines', which was mostly because the business area would get upset and yell at him for underperforming.  Once I knew that, I made sure to work closely with the business area and figure out when a deadline was slipping well in advance.  I'd tell him (and the business area), "Sorry, I'm not going to meet the deadline for X by the end of next month."  And he'd give me some flak and I'd have to defend the deadline being missed... but he didn't get chewed out by the business area (they were given a lot of warning, and they knew I was working hard on their app since they were regularly involved in what I was doing) which in turn reduced the flak I ended up getting from him.  Basically: figure out what stuff is critical to him, and what stuff is fluff.

**Fourth: Focus on the positive.**  Oh, I generally hated my 18 month stint while it happened.  For the most part, it sucked and was a nasty grind.  But there were positives: I got to do an awesome .NET project with a really cool chemical engineer.  I got to really amp up my SQL skills.  I got to experience a hard-core, "if this system goes down, it costs the company $10,000/hour until you can fix it" up-time mindset.  I got to dig into some pretty cool performance algorithms.  Don't get me wrong - the company sucked, the job sucked, and I'm glad I left... but I'm also glad I was there for at least a little bit of time.  The experience I gained was alone worth it in the long run.  So... while the job sucks, try to keep your mind on the positive where it exists.

Answer (score -1):

i had similar issue, toxic manager plus HR-b.tch sold to the manager and upper management (regional, world) who didn't give a sh.t about the situation

basically, in the end the outcome for me has been to quit. sorry, i know that's not what you want to hear but rather have a happy ending solution instead
and yes, i had mortgage and so too

i'd been at war with this manager for years, at first i was naive and just played nice until it started to get ugly (official blaming letters, yelling, threats of any kind including physical and so on)

then i got in touch with a lawyer to respond accordingly and started gathering lots of evidences (emails, secret vocal recordings, etc.) that i could have produced in court if needed

my lawyer written replies didn't really cool things off, although managed to avoid blames to be pined at me since they were just plain bullshit and most of the time totally illegal

colleagues didn't give a sh.t since they didn't want to loose their very well paid jobs and some were even just too happy that whatever happens i would get the heat because i alone always stood up to this manager (even if i was not involved at all, i would get rammed...)

talking to union, well... if they're really loyal to workers (many aren't, so beware) why not but at some point in time i was union and it barely protected me

while i was union, not feeling concerned colleagues turned to me for help when they'd get into trouble from time to time, then they'd go back to pretending they didn't know me once i got them out of trouble, so don't expect much of anyone

you can complain to work inspection, i did several times. finally a work inspector came once but got handled by the HR-b.tch which made sure the inspector didn't see or talk to me, hence the inspector left and nothing happened either

after almost a decade, my health got from bad to worse, i've finally had some very serious health problems
so i went to HR to have things settled with an agreement so that i'd leave with some money given the evidences i had against the manager and the company itself, which happened since HR and the company knew very well that they would have everything to loose in court

so, in short, was it worth it ?

well, i acquired some skills in work laws and justice system so i wont' be f.cked again next time, i also learned a lot about people behaviour and what (not) to expect from them

on the other hand, took me about a decade to recover from some of my health issues although the worst ones are permanent now (sight issue caused by too many prescribed drugs for chronic back pain, cancer and a few others, all stress induced in the first place)

so worth it or not ? i'll let you decide for yourself...

also keep in mind that if laws used to be mostly on the employee side, it's been changing a lot and keeps changing more and more quickly for the worse

good night, and good luck.

Answer (score -1):

I want to say I am really sorry to hear what you are going through; I know it is an awful situation to be in. I am reading a good book called "5 types of people who can ruin your life", which is all about "High Conflict Personalities" and how to deal with them.

I haven't finished it but I can already tell it will be useful, just based on what a remarkable fit the stories are to my own experiences.

I would say that you need to focus on doing your job professionally and ignore his put-downs, and try and find somewhere else ASAP for your own good.

You can wind up being miserable trying to please someone for years, only to have all your efforts thrown back in your face when you finally decide to leave.

I have taken the "no-nonsense" route of calling out slights and attacks and responding in kind, but for someone who has got where they are with toxic behavior you can't beat them at their own game, and people might even see you as a provocateur.

Look after yourself, turn e-mails off when away from work and just try to put him out of your mind (I know it's a lot easier said than done, but try your best). And know that others know what you're going through. Stay strong.